# How to implement pull right to fresh while pulling the last page of a scrollview?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

How to implement pull left to fresh while pulling the last page of a scrollview? i want mimic the popular pulling down to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull down to refresh was done (wrongly) adding a subview to a table view, and monitoring the scroll content offset of the scrollview (table view extends scrollview). I say wrongly, because you can add a tableHeader to do the same thing instead of adding it as a subview.

You need to do it by adding other subviews to your scrollview and then monitoring the scroll offset, the same as what I've just mentioned above.

Look at the methods of UIScrollViewDelegate to see all the different callbacks you get from UIScrollView interaction. It's very versatile.